# Firefox CSS bug with "display:inline-block" and floated elements

Tags: css, firefox

I have a problem in making a particular CSS layout to work with Firefox. What I want to achieve is a column where there are some red boxes that will be in a fixed position and then some other green boxes that will occupy the space available accordingly.

I tested the following fiddles in Chrome and Safari for OSX and IE10 in Win7 and it works great, just as expected. The only problem I have is with Firefox (v31 for OSX, and probably Win too) that is pushing "Item 4" and "Item 8" to the right when using "display: inline-block;" and is cutting them at the bottom when using "display: table;".

using display: inline-block;
http://jsfiddle.net/akrycoem/1/

using display: table;
http://jsfiddle.net/akrycoem/

I searched a lot about "firefox" and "inline-block" but could find just old things related to very old versions (v2 and v3). Could anyone please help me solve this big mystery?
I'd like to avoid using JS for achieving this because I think it would be so much better and faster with just a CSS-only solution, especially with a lots of elements for each column.

Thanks a lot to anyone who could point me in the right direction or even better that could solve my problem!

cheers,

Luca

p.s. here there is the HTML and CSS code that I'm using in the jsfiddle as a reference

### HTML

```
<div class="column">
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div class="redBlock"></div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div class="redBlock"></div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div class="redBlock"></div>
    <ul class="itemsList"><li>Item 1</li><li>Item 2</li><li>Item 3</li><li>Item 4</li><li>Item 5</li><li>Item 6</li><li>Item 7</li><li>Item 8</li><li>Item 9</li><li>Item 10</li></ul>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.column {
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 30px;
    background-color: #333;
}
.column:after {
    content: ".";
    visibility: hidden;
    height: 0;
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}


.spacer {
    width: 0px;
    height: 180px;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    background-color: #00d;
}

.redBlock {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    background-color: #d00;
}



ul.itemsList {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #ddd;
}
ul.itemsList li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    background-color: #0d0;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: I don’t understand what you actually want to _achieve_ here from your description.

Comment: Basically what I need for my app is to have some red boxes that are positioned at variable distance and with variable height. Then there are some green boxes that need to fill the empty space available between the red boxes as best as possible (it's ok if they leave some empty spaces eventually). please see my answer to see a working example in jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the effort GCyrillus, but my problem is that in the app that I'm writing the red blocks must be in fixed positions and are unraleted to the flow of the items. So it's very possible to happen that the space available between the red blocks won't match exactly with the height of the items (that can be variable as well). So what I need is something that can work independently from the height of the boxes.

After some more trials and errors, I managed to find out the problem just a few minutes ago actually! :)

It looks like Firefox doesn't like the .spacer with width:0. For some reason this messes up with the rendering and it's causing the bug.
So I solved it, by giving the .spacer a width:1px and by putting a margin-left:-1px to the .item. And now it magically works across all main browsers! yuuhu :)

http://jsfiddle.net/ky3cqko1/

Thanks again for helping and I hope this will be useful for someone in the future...

### HTML

```
<div class="column">
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div class="redBlock"></div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div class="redBlock"></div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div class="redBlock"></div>
    <div class="itemsList"><div class="item">Item 1</div><div class="item">Item 2</div><div class="item">Item 3</div><div class="item">Item 4</div><div class="item">Item 5</div><div class="item">Item 6</div><div class="item">Item 7</div><div class="item">Item 8</div><div class="item">Item 9</div><div class="item">Item 10</div></div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.column {
    width: 201px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    background-color: #333;
}
.column:after {
    content: ".";
    visibility: hidden;
    height: 0;
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}


.spacer {
    width: 1px;
    height: 180px;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    background-color: #00d;
}

.redBlock {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    background-color: #d00;
}



.itemsList {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #ddd;
}
.item {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    background-color: #0d0;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: -1px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure of what you try to achieve, but , if spacer is 180px high, and that you want to stack 3 lis aside , should not they be each 60px high to fill entire space ?

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/akrycoem/2/)** and **[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/akrycoem/3/)**

```
ul.itemsList li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 60px;
    line-height: 60px;
    background-color: #0d0;
    text-align: center;
}
```

---

You can do something similar with a simple list and drop those spacer and red divs : http://jsfiddle.net/akrycoem/4/

HTML

```
<div class="column">
    <ul class="itemsList">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        <li>Item 4</li>
        <li>Item 5</li>
        <li>Item 6</li>
        <li>Item 7</li>
        <li>Item 8</li>
        <li>Item 9</li>
        <li>Item 10</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.column {
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 30px;
    background-color: red;
}
ul.itemsList {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
ul.itemsList li {
    display: table;
    width: 200px;
    height: 60px;
    line-height: 60px;
    background-color: #0d0;
    text-align: center;
}
ul.itemsList li:nth-child(3n) {
    margin-bottom:100px;
}
```